# ROWNUM doesn't work; trying to grab info on specific row range in SQL query

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a bit of code that counts the number of rows upon an SQL query and then does another query to grab information on the last four rows. I've used `ROWNUM`, but it doesn't work.

```
$newscount = $db->query("
    SELECT *
        FROM news
");
$counter = $newscount->rowCount();
$grabnewsmsg = $db->query("
    SELECT *
        FROM news
        WHERE ROWNUM >= $counter-4 -- this particular part doesn't owrk
        ORDER BY updateno DESC -- an A_I column
");
```

I've commented the specific areas I'm having problems. The `A_I` part is fine, since there should be a unique identifier for each row, but `ROWNUM` just doesn't work despite what I have read on other sites in addition to other questions/answers on SO. It returns an error `column rownum does not exist`.

I want to get information on solely the last four rows (`$query->rowCount()-4`), but I can't select via a certain `updateno` threshhold. If a user deletes a row, the `A_I` column cannot be appropriately used to determine the row number.

Additionally, I've tried the below:

```
$grabnewsmsg = $db->query("
    SELECT *
        FROM news
        ORDER BY updateno DESC
        LIMIT 0,4
");
```

And while this gives the desired results, I'm still not sure why `ROWNUM` doesn't work.

Comment: What "flavor" of SQL are you using?

Comment: @Gidil, I am using PDO.

Comment: Your question is an example of inmafous "XY problem". you have some task to do, you devised some unusual tool to solve, and then ask us how to use that your unusable tool. **While you have to ask how to solve your initial problem**

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `rownum` suggests you are using Oracle, but then `LIMIT` suggests you are using something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand  the meaning of that `AUTO_INC` thingy. It is called an **unique identifier**, and for a reason. "Unique" means **no other row should have the same identifier ever.**

Yet it has absolutely nothing to do with whatever enumeration. So -

> I have an autoincrementing column titled 'updateno' which corresponds to the number of the row.

this is what you are doing wrong.

As a matter of fact, you don't need such a field at all. If you wnat to enumerate your fields - do in on the fly. If you want an **identifier** - use a conventional name for this - `"id"`

While for the whatever "rownum" feature you need another mysql operator, namely LIMIT

Comment: And what if `WHERE ROWNUM > number` doesn't work? It gives me an error stating column ROWNUM does not exist.

Comment: What certain rows you want to have with this "rownum"?

Comment: I see what you mean now after reading your edit. I've removed A_I from `updateno`, and instead when an article is added, I give it a value of `$newsnumber->rowCount()+1`, so it will put in 5 if there's 4 articles, 3 if there's 2, etc. This works fine, thanks for the advice.

Comment: this is wrong again. DON'T thank me if you keep using your awful approach.

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at. `SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY updateno DESC LIMIT 1,4` doesn't give the desired result completely. It seems to pass by the `ORDER BY` part entirely. `LIMIT 1,4` does give 4 rows after the first, but in no way is it ordered (namely descending by updateno value).

Comment: you are still confusing something. Please, please, please pay more attention and don't be too fast with conclusions with the completely new field for you. There are regular solutions that served thousands of programmers for ages. If it doesn't work for you - then it is you are doing something wrong.

Comment: It is confusing because what I can find via Google (most of which are SO questions/answers), none of them work for me. `SELECT * FROM news WHERE ROWNUM >= $counter-4` should work, but it gives me the aforementioned error. I just don't understand why it doesn't work when the Internet tells me it should.

Comment: yeah. that's the problem. A doctor who is searching internet to learn how to perform an appendectomy would scare anyone. But programming considered to be like a children's game and anyone can learn it just by poking internet for a while.